# Problems with Drag and Drop system in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, boolean-logic

I'm a beginner to C# code and having trouble figuring out how to get a certain game feature to work.

I want the player to be able to drag images into slots, press a button to check, and receive feedback depending on if they are correct or incorrect. I got the drag and drop system working correctly, but no matter what slot they drag the image into, it reads as correct.

I tried putting the same tag on the correct slot and image to tell if it's correct, as seen below:

```
if (gameObject.tag == otherObject.tag) {
                correctLetter = true;
                Debug.Log("Correct Letter");
                }
            else{
                correctLetter = false;
            }
```

but no matter the input, it returns as true every time. How do I fix this?

Here's my full code, if needed:

**DragDrop.cs
**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 
public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler, IDropHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Canvas canvas;
 
    private RectTransform rectTransform;
    private CanvasGroup canvasGroup;
 
    private void Awake(){
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }
 
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag");
        canvasGroup.alpha = .6f;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
 
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDrag");
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor;
    }
 
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
        canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }
 
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnPointerDown");
    }
    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**ItemSlot.cs
**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 
public class ItemSlot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public bool correctLetter;
    public GameObject otherObject;
 
    public GameObject objectToDrag;
    public GameObject objectDragTo;
 
    public float dropDistance;
 
 
    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData) {
        correctLetter = false;
 
        Debug.Log("OnDrop");
        if (eventData.pointerDrag != null) {
            eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
 
            if (gameObject.tag == otherObject.tag) {
                correctLetter = true;
                Debug.Log("Correct Letter");
                }
            else{
                correctLetter = false;
            }
 
        }
```

In the following block of code:

```
if (gameObject.tag == otherObject.tag) {
                correctLetter = true;
                Debug.Log("Correct Letter");
                }
            else{
                correctLetter = false;
            }
```

I expected the drag component to only return as true if it had the same tag as the drop component. However, an image (drag) will still return as true when dropped into a slot (drop), even when they don't have the same tag.

Comment: Where do you set the `otherObject` reference?  It is not present in the code above.

Comment: In Unity, I put the corresponding “drag” game object (object being dragged to slot) into the otherObject field, if that’s what you’re asking.

Comment: In that case the object you are comparing against never changes, so it will always be true (if the tag matches).  Instead, set that reference to the object that was dropped.

Comment: This is still a source of confusion for me. For example, let's say I have 3 different "drag" and 3 different "drop" (slot) game objects:

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I set the script to always compare the correct answer to the slot, thus returning as true every time.

Do you know how I would get the compared "Drag" game object to change based on user input?

Comment: It might be the `eventData.pointerDrag` object, but i am not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and see how it goes.